# Embedded ruby inside style width tag

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, styles, width

I'm trying to add embedded ruby into my css style width tag.

Here is what the code currently looks like:

```
<div class = "progress progress-info">
<%target = (((@candidate.civillibscore.to_f)/111.37)*100.0).to_s%>
<div class="bar" style="width: <%target%>%">
```

Not sure if I'm just screwing up the target variable, or if my floats are off (it's printing the right percentage), but any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an equals sign after the `<%` (should be `<%=`):

```
<div class="bar" style="width: <%= target %>%">
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `=` after this code `<%`. So it should look like this `<%=` without `=` the value will not show.